# Magento 2 Hyva: How to add a loader in cart on increasing and decreasing qty using Hyva?

Tags: magento2, cart, shopping-cart, hyva, hyva-themesmagento2-default-theme

> I want to add a Hyva loader on the cart page using the Hyva theme. I
> checked this doc from hyva [Hyva doc loader](https://docs.hyva.io/hyva-themes/view-utilities/loading-indicator.html) but I am not sure
> How I can implement this on increasing and decreasing qty.

**Let me know if anyone has any ideas.**

Thanks.